# Get a specific child from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase, I have a database for an app. Let's say this is my Firebase JSON:

```
{
  "Users" :{
    "User1":{
      "City": "Genk"
    }
    ,"User2":{
      "City": "Hasselt"
    }
    ,"User3":{
      "City": "Genk"
    }
    ,"User4":{
      "City": "As"
    }
    ,"User5":{
      "City": "Genk"
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I want is an ArrayList with all the users with city `Genk`. How is this possible? I want to use this ArrayList to put the specific Users who live in the city `Genk` in a ListView.

Comment: Check this link [https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). Especially on "Sorting and Filtering" section. It has all you want

Comment: @koceeng I read it and I tried it, but it doesn't work. I need to get the child "city" from every child in the database, and order it in a ListView

Comment: It sounds like you've tried something and can't make it work. In that case: share the minimal code that reproduces the problem where you are stuck. You're much more likely to get help that way.

Comment: Parse the json and store the data in an arraylist, then use the removeIf function to remove all users without the city "genk".:)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create another child from the root like "UsersCity", In that way you can just call this child and retrieve it to your listview. Here's what i did:

```
String key = mDatabase.child("post").push().getKey();
UserPost userPost = new UserPost(author,uid,setemoticon,postData,mDate,latlng);
Map<String, Object> postValues = userPost.toMap();

Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                childUpdates.put("/post/" + key,postValues);
                childUpdates.put("/user-post/" + uid + "/" + key, postValues);

mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Here's the Json output for that :

```
{
"post" : {
"-KcGVPpS9CTWPNax61wf" : {
  "authorName" : "Test 1",
  "dateCreated" : {
    "dateCreated" : 1486352395887
  },
  "postDescription" : "sample post",
  "postEmotion" : 2130837658,
  "userId" : "KTcgauWoJugXUsq6TAgrdqUvVYm1"
}
},
"user-post" : {
"KTcgauWoJugXUsq6TAgrdqUvVYm1" : {
  "-KcGVPpS9CTWPNax61wf" : {
    "authorName" : "Test 1",
    "dateCreated" : {
      "dateCreated" : 1486352395887
    },
    "postDescription" : "sample post",
    "postEmotion" : 2130837658,
    "userId" : "KTcgauWoJugXUsq6TAgrdqUvVYm1"
  }
}
},
//This child node is for users where you'll want to get the $uid to use for  creation of other child nodes.
"users" : {
"KTcgauWoJugXUsq6TAgrdqUvVYm1" : {
  "fullname" : "Test 1"
  }
 }
}
```

I am just a newbie programmer and I know my answer is not the best but I hope it could help you out with your problem. :)

Comment: And ooh! The value of mDatabase variable is the main root of your database.

Answer (score 0):

**just fetch specific node data and its working perfect for me**

```
mFirebaseInstance.getReference("yourNodeName").getRef().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "======="+postSnapshot.child("email").getValue());
            Log.e(TAG, "======="+postSnapshot.child("name").getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read app title value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```